# DRM/Easypal/Digital SSTV programatic generation resources?

Tags: sstv

I've come across plenty of resources for programmatically transmitting SSTV images and/or broadcasts (including [dnet's](https://ham.stackexchange.com/users/5068/dnet) [pySSTV](https://github.com/dnet/pySSTV)/[UnixSSTV](https://github.com/dnet/unixsstv) and [Oona Räisänen's](https://github.com/windytan) [slowrx](https://github.com/windytan/slowrx)), but none yet for it's error corrected, higher quality cousin: [DRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Radio_Mondiale) (aka [EasyPal or Digital SSTV](http://www.g6hoq.com/easypal.htm)).

Do useful open code libraries or examples exist? Such as for GRC, high level code(such as Python) or Linux libraries?

(*Note*: I'm interested in the use of DRM for the transmission of data and images)

Comment: DRM is an _audio_ mode. Why do you compare it to SSTV?

Comment: @KevinReidAG6YO My understanding is thatt can be used for SSTV / the transmission of images. I've added some more info above.

Answer (score 1):

By programatically you mean through command line and/or scriptable ?

I was looking for a linux app for DRM digital SSTV compatible with EasyPal and found TXRXAMADRM:
http://pa0mbo.nl/ties/public_html/hamradio/txamadrm/

It comes with an executable for sending, one for receiving as well as a GUI wrapping them. Just managed to compile them but couldn't test them yet as i'm waiting for the data cable to connect my transceiver to my PC.
So i guess you could use directly the tx and rx apps from your scripts.

QSSTV (http://users.telenet.be/on4qz/) seems reuing parts of TRXAMADRM as well, but comes only with a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

For GRC I have only come across:

- [GR-DRM](https://github.com/kit-cel/gr-drm) / [GNU Radio DRM](https://github.com/fewu/gnuradio_drm) GRC Examples.

Both are audio only and I do not have personal experience of the use / respective pros and cons.